# How do I retrieve a single piece of data from a website from java?

Tags: java, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

I am creating a process in my java program that needs to retrieve the stock prices from Yahoo Finance and I can't figure out how to do it nor do I know where to start. So far I have it so that it can connect to any specific stock page that I want it to but I'm not sure how to go about retrieving the current stock price.

`urlName = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" + ticker + "&ql=0";
    URL url = new URL(urlName);
    // Get the input stream through URL Connection
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    InputStream is =con.getInputStream();
    con.connect();`

Comment: Use the API as others suggested. Just note that If you go for parsing the HTML, then later if the website undergoes any changes - then your code will have change too.

Answer (score 2):

You can go about it one of two ways:

(1) Easy way: use the Yahoo Finance API: http://yahoofinance-api.com/

(2) Hard way:  Parse the html source code for the price.

Answer (score 1):

Open a reader on stream. Get the source code in a string and  then analyze the source code for the tag that contains your info the use xml parsing to get that info.you can use tiddy library in java.

Answer (score 1):

Do you specifically want to crawl the website to do this as an exercise?  It would be much easier to use a library like this: https://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/YahooFinanceAPIs

If you do want to crawl, you can use an HttpConnection or Apache HttpClient to get the HTML then use a library like JSoup to parse and interpret the data.